# Video plays only once using webview

Tags: android, webview

When I play the video first time using webview it plays fine but once I select the backkey and select the video again it loads ok but then goes into pause and refuses to play. I get the message below in the console log when this happens.

Any help you can give would be very much appreciated.

[HTML5VideoView] onAudioFocusChange() called. videoView = android.webkit.HTML5VideoInline@4238a998 [HTML5VideoView] onAudioFocusChange() - pause()

Comment: Did you eventually solve it?

Comment: Check here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20379478/android-samsung-s4-html5-video-pauses